# What rendering engine does Ionic use?

Tags: ionic-framework

Can't seem to find which rendering engine the mobile app wrapper [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) uses. **Is it Webkit?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with a programming problem; it's a question about which underlying framework a third-party product uses.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling The question does relate to programming since the rendering engine used will determine which HTML/CSS features a developer can use when building an Ionic app. Since it's not doing any harm, I vote to leave open. Perhaps the wording can be made more relevant however.

Comment: Leave it open, it's absolutely related to programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ionic's Cordova is essentially opening a webview from the native app. That means the rendering engine is different on every device. For example, on the latest devices, Android uses webkit, and iOS uses WkWebView. That's where you have to be careful. Some styling like css-animation behaves differently.

Comment: One way to at least lessen the impact of such inconsistent native browser behavior for Android devices could be to distribute your cordova app with [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html). However, that makes the  .apk file  size rather heavy.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer:

If you wish to have the same experience across the platform, you could always resolve to using the crosswalk plugin. On android, it basically installs the webkit and uses it instead of the native webview, so that it will always display the same across devices. On iOS, there is a similar version for the iOS8 and up to use the new wkWebView and not the old uiwebview. Just google cordova crosswalk and it should come up.